# Hide Columns in Grid by Default

Tags: acumatica

With a new custom screen/graph/DAC, how can I make columns in a grid hidden *by default*? That is I want the column / controls in the Grid but only shown if the user goes in to the Column Configuration and selects to add it.
(These are purely informational columns on the grid of a custom Processing screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visibility of DAC fields is controlled by PXUIField attribute properties.

- The 'Visible' property determines whether or not the field is shown on screen.
- The 'Visibility' property determines whether or not the field is available for display.

For your use case, you want to hide it by default (Visible = false) and make it available for display in the grid column selection dialog (Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible):

```
[PXUIField(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible, Visible = false)]
```

You can also set these properties using static functions instead of DAC field attributes:

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisibility(cache, null, typeof(DAC.field).Name, PXUIVisibility.Visible);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible(cache, null, typeof(DAC.field).Name, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the DAC or Graph you can set the fields Visible property to false

Example found on sales order for the "Line Order" field.

```
#region SortOrder
public abstract class sortOrder : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected Int32? _SortOrder;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = AP.APTran.sortOrder.DispalyName, Visible = false, Enabled = false)]
[PXDBInt]
public virtual Int32? SortOrder
{
    get
    {
        return this._SortOrder;
    }
    set
    {
        this._SortOrder = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```